# I Want Convert Hex to Ascii

Tags: c#, hex, ascii, data-conversion

I want convert hex to ascii.

[image: The file contents are as follows]

I was try different two methods. But I could not be successful.

Method1:

```
 public void ConvertHex(String hexString)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            String hs = hexString.Substring(i, i + 2);
            System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(hexString.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
        }
        String ascii = sb.ToString();
        StreamWriter wrt = new StreamWriter("D:\\denemeASCII.txt");
        wrt.Write(ascii);

    }
```

Method 2:

```
 public string HEX2ASCII(string hex)
    {
        string res = String.Empty;
        for (int a = 0; a < hex.Length; a = a + 2)
        {
            string Char2Convert = hex.Substring(a, 2);
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Char2Convert, 16);
            char c = (char)n;
            res += c.ToString();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Incoming error message :(

[image: error message]

What should I do?

Comment: Please paste code instead of images

Comment: ok. i'm adding.

Comment: You are trying to convert a hexadecimal number, which is composed of the digits 0 through F, to Int32. The parser will throw an exception when it hits one of the A~F digits, because they are letters. The Int32 parser has no idea they are actually hex digits.

Comment: is the white-letters-on-black-background image supposed to be somehow pertinent to the question, or is it purely decorative?  If it is pertinent, then you might want to explain what it shows.  Is it the content of a text file that you want to parse? Is it the result of a hex dump that you are trying to imitate?  In either case, "convert hex to ascii" is ***not*** what you want, so the presence of that image is quite odd.

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of an exception or error message isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

Your "Method1" has a few chances of being rewritten to work.  (Your "Method2" is hopeless.)

So, in "Method1", you do `String hs = hexString.Substring( i, i + 2 )` and then you forget that `hs` ever existed. (Shouldn't the compiler be giving you a warning about that?) Then you proceed to do `System.Convert.ToChar( System.Convert.ToUInt32( hexString.Substring( 0, 2 ), 16 ) )` but `hexString.Substring( 0, 2 )` will always pick the first two characters of the `hexString`, not the two characters pointed by `i`. What you probably meant to do is this instead: `System.Convert.ToChar( System.Convert.ToUInt32( hs , 16) )`

Also, you are declaring a `StringBuilder sb;` but you are never adding anything to it. At the same time, `System.Convert.ToChar()` does not work by side effect; it returns a value; if you don't do anything with the returned value, the returned value is lost forever.  What you probably meant to do is add the result of `System.Convert.ToChar()` to your `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have valid character in your input.  A character in c# is two bytes class with a private property which indicates if the character is one or two bytes.  The encoding library methods (unicode, UTF6, UTF7, UTF8) normally does the conversion and sets the private property.  It is hard to tell with your input if you are converting to one or two bytes, and if the input is big endian or little endian.  The code below converts to byte[] and int16[].

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "0178 0000 0082 f000 0063 6500 00da 6400 00be 0000 00ff ffff ffff ffff ffd6 6600";
            ConvertHex(input);
        }
        static void ConvertHex(String hexString)
        {
            Int16[] hexArray = hexString.Split(new char[] {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(x => Int16.Parse(x, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();

            byte[] byteArray = hexArray.Select(x => new byte[] { (byte)((x >> 8) & 0xff), (byte)(x & 0xff) }).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int16[] hexArray = hexStri... this code give error.

Comment: There must be other characters in your input like '\n'.  Try : new char[] {' ', '\t', '\r', '\n'}

Comment: The data you posted works.  If you post the bad data I would have a chance of modifying the code.

Comment: [link](https://yadi.sk/d/JMUIN0_63JEWQE) I was uploaded the file, please help me.